# What are the queries run by Datagrip's import CSV?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I'm using DataGrip's import CSV into database option, as show here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/importexport.html

But I want to understand what are the queries that DataGrip is running against my DataBase. I'm using MS SQL SERVER 2012.

By clicking in the DDL PREVIEW tab I can see the following snippet:

```
CREATE TABLE VESSEL_POSITIONS.dbo.[SOFS_T-AIS]
(
    imo INT,
    MESSAGE_SOURCE TEXT,
    MSG_SRC_COUNT INT
)
```

but I want to understand how the actual insertions are done.

This seems a bit too magical and I want to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the executed statements, either using [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-2017) session, or using [Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017). The recommended way is to use Extended Events. You need to create a session and specify which events you are interested in, and where to store the captured data. In SSMS open a query window and run this query:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Capture_Datagrip_Queries]
ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(
    ACTION 
    (
            sqlserver.sql_text
    )
    WHERE 
    (
            database_id = 9
    )
)
ADD TARGET package0.event_file
(
    SET filename = 'D:\XE\Datagrip.xel',
        max_file_size = 5,
        max_rollover_files = 1
)
```

Place the database_id of the database where the queries will run (it's 9 in my example). You can get it by executing this query `select db_id(N'MyDatabaseName')`. This will reduce the overhead by capturing only the relevant information, but otherwise the where part is optional. Also keep in mind, that the file will be created on the computer where SQL Server runs. Don't add a path from your local computer. Also, you can add additional information to be captured, if you want to.

After your created this session, you can start/stop it using these queries:

```
ALTER EVENT SESSION [Capture_Datagrip_Queries] ON SERVER STATE = START
ALTER EVENT SESSION [Capture_Datagrip_Queries] ON SERVER STATE = STOP
```

Or in SSMS using `Management \ Extended Events \ Sessions` node in Object Explorer. Do not leave the session running for longer than needed.

You can see the results in SSMS - there is a `package0.event_file` node under the session. Double click it to see the collected data.

Answer (score 2):

You can observe **all** queries run by DataGrip in Full SQL Log.

[image]